# Cygwin Drush throws error in Drupal folders

Tags: drush

In my Windows machine I have installed Drush using Cygwin & PEAR. Though it runs fine when I run `drush`; shows me all the available commands but when I run any `drush` command inside a Drupal folder its throws me an error saying:

```
`require_once(d:/wamp/www/d7/modules/system/system.module): failed to open stream: No such file or directory drupal.inc:21                                                          [warning]
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'd:/wamp/www/d7/modules/system/system.module' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/share/pear/drush/includes/drupal.inc on line 21
require_once(d:/wamp/www/d7/modules/system/system.module): failed to open stream: No such file or directory drupal.inc:21                                                          [warning]
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'd:/wamp/www/d7/modules/system/system.module' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/share/pear/drush/includes/drupal.inc on line 21
`
```

Even tried creating a `symlink` in my www folder but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Drush.  It would be nice if someone was available to work on a fix; the [solution more-or-less exists in the issue](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/1226).  Testing needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Working for the time being though as you suggested it needs a better solution.